# Python watchdog handling network shares that disappear

Tags: python, watchdog, network-shares

I am trying to monitor network shares on about 20 different machines and everything works when the machines are on. However, if the machine is rebooted the observer crashes or if the share isn't available initially.

What would be a method of handling the issue where if I have an observer on a folder and that share disappears it will reattach when the share becomes available again?

When the share disappears I get the following exception.

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\winapi.py", line 108, in _errcheck_bool
    raise ctypes.WinError()
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid.
```